# Xamarin.Forms background image not working on iOS, works on Android

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, background, xamarin.forms

I'm building my first real app with Xamarin.Forms (I have experience with Android already), and I'm trying to add a background image to my app. Here's the Xaml I'm using, note the `BackgroundImage` property on the `ContentPage`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
        x:Class="TnpApp.Forms.HomeScreen"
        BackgroundImage="NarrowPathBackground.png" > <!-- ## Here it is ## -->
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Padding="30">
            <Button Text="Radio"/>
            <Button Text="Topical Messages"/>
            <Button Text="Commentary Messages"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

The background image shows up perfectly on Android, but when I deploy to any iOS emulator I get this:

[image: Screenshot]

If I remove the BackgroundImage property in the XAML, the background is pure white. However, when I add the property the background darkens and shows a blurred and faded version of the image.

As you can see in the screenshot, I can display the image perfectly in an `Image` XAML element, it's just not working for the background.

I've added the image to a new image set in my `Assets.xcassets`, but that isn't fixing anything.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to show the image normally in the background?

Comment: I could not reproduce this on my end. Are you on the latest stable versions of Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin .Forms?

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for checking. Yes, I'm up to date in the Stable channel.

Comment: Where did you put the image(s)? I'm wondering if I may have a problem there, but not sure.

Comment: I have the same problem, my Images are in Android drawable forlder and in iPhone it's in Resources folder (where the icons are placed for both)

Comment: @ChandreshKhambhayata are you using Assets.xcassets at all?

Comment: @Jonathan no my Images are placed in the `Resources` folder, actually, I can see the images in Image source but I can not see it in background.

Comment: I tested both with the image in the Resources folder and in an xcassets Image Set. Both worked on my end.